# Processing large number of records with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

what is the best approach to load a collection and update all items with NHibernate. The current code loads 50 objects and processes each in its own transaction (if 1 fail others are OK).

NH Profiler says that there are too many sql queries per session.

After all, what do you think about this code?

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            var myCollection =
                (from obj in session.Query<MyObject>()
                 select obj).Take(50);

            foreach (var item in myCollection)
            {
                using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //  Do some stuff...
                        session.Update(item);
                        tx.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        tx.Rollback();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [**NHibernate: Streaming large result sets**](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/06/27/nhibernate-streaming-large-result-sets.aspx) :

> NHibernate is meant to be used in an
>   OLTP system, as such, it is usually
>   used in cases where we want to load a
>   relatively small amount of data from
>   the database, work with it and save it
>   back. For reporting scenarios, there
>   are better alternatives, usually (and
>   before you ask, any reporting package
>   will do. Right tool for the job, etc).
>
> But there are cases where you want to
>   do use NHibernate in reporting
>   scenarios nonetheless. Maybe because
>   the reporting requirements aren’t
>   enough to justify going to a separate
>   tool, or because you want to use what
>   you already know. It is in those cases
>   where you tend to run into problems,
>   because you violate the assumptions
>   that were made while building
>   NHibernate.

```
using (IStatelessSession s = sessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession())
{
    var books = new ActionableList<Book>(book => Console.WriteLine(book.Name));
    s.CreateQuery("from Book")
        .List(books);

}
```

> The stateless session, unlike the
>   normal NHibernate session, doesn’t
>   keep track of loaded objects, so the
>   code here and the data reader code are
>   essentially the same thing.

Basically, use a stateless session and batching. Read also: [NHibernate Perf Tricks](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/22/nhibernate-perf-tricks.aspx)

Comment: Per the original question, how would you /update/ each record without loading all the records into memory at the same time?

Comment: @pettys In that case, I would use pure HQL and ExecuteUpdate() -> http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct

Comment: That makes sense. Pure HQL or SQL is a good solution for trivial CRUD operations. For non-trivial domain aggregates, HQL or SQL would bypass the domain logic. Example: an event occurs where 500 customers just earned the "Preferred Customer!" status. When I call Customer.MakePreferred() there are domain events which send congratulatory emails and make calculation-oriented adjustments to other values in the system. I realize I'm hand-crafting a worst-case scenario here - just seeing what other ideas it might bring up.

Answer (score 0):

How many query do you have ? Maybe you afre suffering the `select N+1` problem, because you are acceding lazy properties on each object in your "do stuff" part. Try to load eagerly all the portion you need on the object joining them on the first query.

Comment: There is no select+1 problem. I just had the feeling that I did the things wrong.